# Awesomium Popup - ShowCreatedWebView Example

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, popupwindow, awesomium

I'm working with Awesomium 1.7.4.2 with `C# Windows Forms` in Visual Studio 2012. I'm not able to open a popup window by click of a hyperlink.

I have a `WebControl` in form and `ShowCreatedWebView` am capturing the event, but inside I do not know how to open a new window popup child passing the data to POST.

I know I must use `ShowCreatedWebView` and tried unsuccessfully to use the SDK sample:

http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_ShowCreatedWebView

It just does not work!

Can anyone give an example in `C# windows forms`?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

Remember to add `target="_blank"` in your hyperlink:

```
<a id="foo" href="http://...." target="_blank">Test link</a>
```

and then all you need is to capture `ShowCreatedWebView` event, like this:

```
webControl1.ShowCreatedWebView += OnShowNewView;

internal static void OnShowNewView( object sender, ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e )
{
    // Your link is in e.TargetURL
    // You can handle it like in docs you've mentioned 
}
```

You can open it with external browser, like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.TargetURL.ToString());
```

You can handle it like in Awesomium docs:

```
    internal static void OnShowNewView(object sender, ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e)
    {
        WebControl webControl = sender as WebControl;

        if (webControl == null)
            return;

        if (!webControl.IsLive)
            return;

        ChildWindow newWindow = new ChildWindow();

        if (e.IsPopup && !e.IsUserSpecsOnly)
        {
            Int32Rect screenRect = e.Specs.InitialPosition.GetInt32Rect();

            newWindow.NativeView = e.NewViewInstance;
            newWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            newWindow.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
            newWindow.ResizeMode = e.Specs.Resizable ? ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip : ResizeMode.NoResize;

            if ((screenRect.Width > 0) && (screenRect.Height > 0))
            {
                newWindow.Width = screenRect.Width;
                newWindow.Height = screenRect.Height;
            }
            newWindow.Show();
            if ((screenRect.Y > 0) && (screenRect.X > 0))
            {
                newWindow.Top = screenRect.Y;
                newWindow.Left = screenRect.X;
            }
        }
        else if (e.IsWindowOpen || e.IsPost)
        {
            newWindow.NativeView = e.NewViewInstance;
            newWindow.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            newWindow.Source = e.TargetURL;
            newWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```